# Spring Boot authorization using JWT

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Am I correct in the following thought process?

For a native app I'm building I want to implement a backend in Spring Boot.
This backend will be secured using Spring Security. Since I will manage and develop everything myself (the backend, the native app(s) and the web app for backend management) securing everything with JWT would be sufficient and implementing a full oauth server would be a bit overkill.

I have implemented the JWT token generation in my backend at this moment. On user sign in, the backend returns a json object containing some user details as well as an access token and a refresh token. The access token will be short lived, the refresh token will be long-lived (speaking about months of life time, maybe even indefinite unless revoked).

Is it correct that the refresh token could theoretically also be used as the access token? Or should I set some value/data in the refresh token that identifies it as a refresh token only (so can't be used to access resources, only to generate new access token)?

Comment: Theoretically you could use your refresh token as an access token as well, but potentially that would be a huge security leak as well as redundancy of access token itself (I don't need short-living one if I have long-living). I would use refresh token to refresh my access token only! Also signatures of refresh and access token should differ, and I wouldn't accept refresh token without access token (expired, but with valid signature).

Comment: What do you mean with signatures should differ? Should I use a different secret for signing the refresh token?

For the rest your answer seems clear to me and it seems that I am on the right track with this.

Comment: "Should I use a different secret for signing the refresh token?" - yes, I would make the secrets different.